# Filter geom_text value labels in a stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a stacked bar chart with ggplot, and add (centered) labels to it: when values are too low, I don't want to show the label.

```
df<-data.frame(x=unlist(strsplit("AAAABBBB","")),
           z=unlist(strsplit("ABCDABCD","")),
           y=c(40,5,30,10,50,60,5, 40))

# this works fine
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = z)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
   geom_text(data  = df, aes(x=x, y=y, label = y), position = position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

But when I filter the values like this (see below), it also changes the positioning for each label. This works fine for a scatterplot, but since the positioning is based on the stacked values, the labels are shown too low.

```
#don't show values 5 or less
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = z)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    geom_text(data = df[df$y > 5,], aes(x=x, y=y, label = y), position = 
    position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a column 'y1' with value that are less than or equal to 5 as blank (`""`) and use that in the `label` argument

```
df %>% 
     mutate(y1 = replace(y, y<=5, ""))

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = z)) + 
         geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
         geom_text(data  = df, aes(x=x, y=y, label = y1),
                  position = position_stack(vjust=0.5))
p2
```

[image]

---

Checking for the position by comparing with the first plot from the OP's post

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = z)) + 
                  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
                  geom_text(data  = df, aes(x=x, y=y, label = y), 
                      position = position_stack(vjust=0.5))

library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol =2, nrow = 1, labels = c("p1", "p2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. There was some weird issue that I wasn't aware about, will try to solve it latter. Your solution is very good, however I wouldn't create new column, but would do something like that: `aes(label = ifelse(y > 5, y, ""))`

Comment: @PoGibas  I guess that is the way.  I saw that you were doing something similar, so didn't change it